# IP validation inconsistent from php 5.6.25

Tags: php, validation, filter-var

Can anyone explain why the following code returns truthy in < 5.6.25, and false for everything above?
My understanding is it should be truthy, as `192.168.0.1` is a valid internal IP.

`var_dump(filter_var('192.168.0.1', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_IPV4));`

See results across versions: https://3v4l.org/u9OFt

Answer (score 3):

192.168.x is in the reserved range for class C addresses and you have specified FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE to exclude them.

It's possible this was a fixed bug in 5.6.25 onwards, with a regression in the initial versions of 7.x

Comment: I may be confusing reserved and private here.

Comment: Makes sense. I was misreading `FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE` as _allowing_ reserved ranges. I can't seem to find reference to the change in the changelog, although it does make sense they way it is now

Comment: `Filter:
Fixed bug #71745 (FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE does not cover whole 127.0.0.0/8 range` @shauno